# Select only most recent records from all results where username = x?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am currently trying to create some form of instant messenger for my website, allowing users to communicate with one another. To do this, I created a sql table, called `messages` with the headings `id, senderID, recipientID, timestamp, message`.

At the moment, I am trying to work out how to create a list of all **conversations** (not individual messages) for a given user with `id = x`. This list should contain only the most recent message sent to user x, from each sender y1, y2, y3, ...

For example, consider the table

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  senderID  |  recipientID  |  timestamp  |  message  |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     14     |      34       | 2017-06-21  | Hello ... |
|  2   |     14     |      37       | 2017-06-22  | How ar... |
|  3   |     11     |      34       | 2017-06-23  | I was ... |
|  4   |     17     |      34       | 2017-06-24  | Good  ... |
|  5   |     18     |      34       | 2017-06-25  | My na ... |
|  6   |     11     |      34       | 2017-06-26  | I've  ... |
|  7   |     14     |      34       | 2017-06-27  | Thank ... |
|  8   |     12     |      34       | 2017-06-28  | I nee ... |
|  9   |     17     |      34       | 2017-06-29  | Have  ... |
|  10  |     17     |      34       | 2017-06-30  | You h ... |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, suppose that I am user 34 and I wish to view a list containing the most recent message from each `senderID` to myself. What is the SQL query that would do this? I.e. what SQL query would give the following result:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  senderID  |  recipientID  |  timestamp  |  message  |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|  5   |     18     |      34       | 2017-06-25  | My na ... |
|  6   |     11     |      34       | 2017-06-26  | I've  ... |
|  7   |     14     |      34       | 2017-06-27  | Thank ... |
|  8   |     12     |      34       | 2017-06-28  | I nee ... |
|  10  |     17     |      34       | 2017-06-30  | You h ... |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

What SQL commands are used to give this result?

Comment: where recipientID = 34 order by timestamp DESC

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.recipientId = 34 and
      m.timestamp = (select max(m2.timestamp)
                     from messages m2
                     where m2.senderId = m.senderId and m2.recipientId = m.recipientId
                    );
```

`IN`, `EXISTS`, and `JOIN`/`GROUP BY` would all do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipientId = 34 ORDER BY timestamp DESC;

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer:

1. create a table named `messages_latest`, the columns is same with the table `messages`;
2. when one user with `id = 1` send message to user with `id = 34`, first remove message from table `messages_latest` where `senderID = 1` and `recipientId = 34`, and then insert latest record into `messages_latest`;

the table `message_latest` saves the most recent messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second query to get `MAX(timestamp)` group by `recipientID` and `senderID` and just join with the `messages` table on those same fields and `ORDER BY timestamp ASC`.

That way, you filter only the last message sent from each `senderID` to the specified `recipientID` in the `WHERE` clause.

```sql
select m.*
from messages as m
  join ( select recipientID, senderID, max(timestamp) as timestamp
         from messages
         group by recipientID, senderID ) as l
  on m.recipientID = l.recipientID
    and m.senderID = l.senderID         
    and m.timestamp = l.timestamp
where m.recipientID = 34
order by m.timestamp asc
```

You can find a working SqlFiddle here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63a42/18